# WPF Rendering Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection

I have a wpf app that uses Transitionals to do some animation.  My main screen has a element like this:

```
<transitionalsControls:TransitionElement Name="DisplayPage" Width="1024" Height="768">
  <transitionalsControls:TransitionElement.Transition>
    <transitionalsTransitions:RotateTransition Duration="0:0:0.5" Angle="90" />
  </transitionalsControls:TransitionElement.Transition>
</transitionalsControls:TransitionElement>
```

The first time I do

```
DisplayPage.Content = someUserControl;
```

I get a long delay in rendering.  Sometimes is half a second, sometimes its in the range of 5 seconds.  When I look at it in "Diagnotic Tools" the "Process Memory" advances over time until I set someUserControl.  When I do that, it stops for the duration of the rendering issue.  When it finally draws, the Process Memory bar resumes and there's a yellow tick where the delay occurred indicating garbage collection.  When I inspect it, it's an unforced Gen 1 garbage collection and the duration is just a few miliseconds.

I removed everything except a few labels and the problem still persists.

Is this rendering delay garbage collection and if so how do I get around it?  This is basically at application startup and looks terrible.  After it happens the app runs just fine.

Any ideas?  I've tried everything I can think of to force GC and side step the issue but nothing has made any difference.

Comment: Some profiler images/dumps would be helpful. But it sounds like you hit an expensive view constructor. Perhaps your user control assembly is loaded at this point too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to define transition controls inside XAML code in transitioner host control.
When you reset controls from C# code, they may be collected by GC and need to recreate them.